# Повесить 1 триггер на все таблицы

Tags: sql-server

Допустим, есть БД и в каждой таблице этой БД есть некоторая колонка в которую нужно писать дату последнего апдейта при апдейте.

Решение в лоб- это повесить на каждую таблицу по триггеру.

Однако, можно ли сделать всего 1 триггер?

Comment: Нельзя. Да и как вы это себе представляете с точки зрения серверного компилятора-оптимизатора запросов?

Comment: @Yaant, динамические запросы же как-то оптимизируются же...